# Draw borders on line chartjs

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm using ChartJS to create a line chart with elements. I'm wondering if it possible to set borders on left and right of a element? This is my chart and it gets confusing if you have two elements next to each other and they have the same color.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97r5w.png]

I've found nothing in the docs that supports it, so I figure that I have to draw it myself using js but I was hoping someone had an solution first :)
In case I have to draw it myself I would run into a problem since every element can have different widths due to the time axis (X). What would be your idea to solve that?

Update

Every element in the chart is a new dataset and gets a gradient object as backgroundColor and fill sets as true. Here is an example of me pushing a new dataset into the chart

```js
chart.data.datasets.push({
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: gradient,
                data: [
                {
                    x: aIstartX,
                    y: yAxis_value,
                    .. Other attributes
                },
                {
                    x: newEntryXend,
                    y: yAxis_value,
                    ..Other attributes
                }]
            });
```

```js
xAxes: [
                        {
                            stacked: false,
                            type: 'time',
                            unit: 'minute',
                            position: 'bottom',
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true
                            },
                            time: {
                                displayFormats: {
                                    'minute': 'mm:ss'
                                }
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                autoSkip: true,
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize: 2,
                                autoSkipPadding: 5,
                                padding: 10,
                                labelOffset: 5,
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                tickMarkLength: 20
                            },
                        }
                        ]
```

Here is a fiddle of my issue

https://jsfiddle.net/fa8hvhtv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. The issue was that I was trying to create some space between my datasets and my datas attribute Y doesnt start and end at 0. Therefor I added two extra datapoints in each dataset with a borderWidth of 3 and borderColor that matches the backgroundColor of the chart. Each extra added datapoint will have a Y with the value of 0. An example of adding a dataset to my chart is below.

```
chart.data.datasets.push({
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: gradient,
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderColor: '#333',
            data: [
            {
                x: startXvalue,
                y: 0
            },
            {
                x: startXvalue,
                y: startY,
                .. Other attributes
            },
            {
                x: newEntryXend,
                y: endY,
                .. Other attributes
            },
            {
                x: newEntryXend,
                y : 0
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can wanted to keep the same background colors for ,

Why cant you try as below

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y6y40ot6/1/)

```
fill: true,
backgroundColor: 'red',
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The color has value and therefor it is not possible to use a new color for each element.